# Intellisense for Python is Visual Studio 2022 not suggesting anything

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Is it possible to set the Intellisense lines in Visual Studio like in pycharm?

In visual studio I have nothing...

Pycharm has this:

[image]

In Visual Studio 2022, I have only this (nothing appears after typing `.`):

[image]

Comment: What are "help lines"? Do you mean the suggestions that appear after typing `.`?

Comment: @TimothyG. yes and information about inputs in functions

Comment: Unless I misunderstand what you are asking, this behavior is enabled by default. For example, see this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5oqm.png  This is with C# code though - do you mean for Python code in Visual Studio?

Comment: @TimothyG. yes and the sugestions/list of def function.

Comment: So this should be [Intellisense](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/editing-python-code-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#intellisense).  I'm unsure how Python really works in Visual Studio.  It does support it, and in my basic testing it seems that it works for me, but I your code seems a bit more complex than my simple test.